# How to do Image type validation in magento.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I am new to magento. I just want to do image validation in magento but i am struggling alot. I used ajax validation but append() function in jquery is not supporting in magento, So i dont know how to do this.

My ajax code:

```
           jQuery(function () { 
    var url =  jQuery('#image_url').val();
    var vendorImage = jQuery('#vendor_logo');
     vendorImage.on("change", function () {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var file = jQuery('#vendor_logo')[0].files[0];
        if (file) {   
            fd.append('vendor_logo', file);

        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: fd,
            success: function (result) { 
                alert(0);
                alert(result);
                jQuery("#output").html("Upload success.");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I am getting error for append() function.

I think It would be better if i use add rule in validation.js file
My code here:

```
        Validation.add('validate-imgtype', 'Please choos valid image', function(v) {
        var Image = jQuery(v).val();
        var extension = Image.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
        if (extension!="PNG" && extension!="JPG" && extension!="GIF" && extension!="JPEG"){
            return extension;
        }
       });
```

But the above add rule code also not working.

Can anyone help me to resolve this???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for image validation in magento you can try doing

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
  {
    if(isset($_FILES['myfileupload']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['myfileupload']['tmp_name'])))
    {
      $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/myfileupload';
      if(!file_exists($path))
      { mkdir($path, 777, true); }

      try {
      $myfileupload = $_FILES['myfileupload']['name'];
      $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('myfileupload');
      $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf'));
      $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
      $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
      $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
      $uploader->save($path, $myfileupload);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error';
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have given code for normal form submit. I am asking to send the image details through Ajax and validate in controller.